# How do I automatically upload file in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm able to manually upload a file to Google Colab using the following code.

```
1  import json
2  from google.colab import files
3  uploaded = files.upload()
```

Each time it reaches `Line 3`, I'll have to manually click `Upload File`, then select the file locally before the code continues to run. After a few runs, even if I cancel the upload at `Line 3`, it seems to run just fine without uploading the file.

How do you automatically upload the same file (stored locally) each time you run the code in Google Colab? Or should I store it in Google Drive and link the file's URL? If so, how would I do that in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, I was able to upload /link files in Google Colab

```
'''store a file in google drive and create a shareable link, change "file/d" to "uc?export=download&" and remove /view?usp=sharing. 
This will create a link that you can store in a variable example below'''
#link = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n2ZS50c_WbHBK9gIco4gRAUSm9uWfo3Q/view?usp=sharing'
# replace 'file/d/' with 'uc?export=download&id=' and remove '/view?usp=sharing'
#link = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1n2ZS50c_WbHBK9gIco4gRAUSm9uWfo3Q'

'''Direct file link can also be saved to variable as below '''
# User inputs
fileLink = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pavanghai/DataSets/master/games.csv"
fileType = "csv"
fileLink1 = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1n2ZS50c_WbHBK9gIco4gRAUSm9uWfo3Q'
```

or you can create a download file as below

```
# Download a filelink as file in google root folder "/content/"
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pavanghai/DataSets/master/games.csv -q
```

-q is quite mode